# Exchange 2007 server-side trigger to call web service on meeting request update/deletion

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange

I'd appreciate if somebody could help me with the following.

When an Exchange 2007 meeting request is updated/deleted, I'd like to call a web service. Is it possible to set up a server-side trigger that would do the call?

**EDIT:** It's also important to note that when the web service is called, I need to pass in the meeting request ID and the delta (in case of an update).

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no way to have Exchange call an external URL when something happens, I think the best you can do is use EWS to monitor a calendar and call your web service based on that.

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to find an answer myself of course. And it's been some time already that I did find a quite acceptable solution.

And yes, Sam, using EWS (Exchange Web Services) is exactly what can help here, as you correctly pointed out. Actually, EWS is what my solution is based on.

So, part of EWS is the notion of Event Notifications. And that's it. As simple as it is. It's only that such notifications cannot contain any valuable information besides the item ID. Because in case the item has been updated I'd like to know the delta. And if I don't get it, I have to retrieve it. But that's not a huge deal after all, since EWS allows me to easily retrieve the delta by the ID.

As to how to utilize EWS, there's EWS Managed API, for example, that offers a handy client.

(However I must say that I haven't implemented the described solution yet. I'll do it a bit later. Therefore all I've written here is mainly from a theoretical point of view.)